# jquery Image Wheelzoom with angularjs not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using jquery wheelzoom for image zoom functionality. It works fine with without angular but not working when I use images in angular repeater.

Comment: Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/uv87bk4e/1/

Comment: It's better to include everything in the question itself instead of in the comments. Just click on the edit link under the tags.

Comment: "It works fine with without angular"?

Comment: wheelzoom works fine, if I am not using ng-repeat but with ng-repeat it is not working. Please check the fiddle example. it helps you to understand what I want to say.

Comment: But both of the samples don't work? Your "Without Repeate" sample shows the image, but the zoom isn't working either?

Comment: Please scroll the mouse wheel and then check . http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/ This is the reference from where check wheelzoom functionality

Comment: I have set up a plnkr with both angular and non-angular call to wheelzoom for better understanding. http://plnkr.co/edit/Qd8yliUSb7Tx5C3Q7Bue?p=preview. At first I thought that the only problem you had was showing the images in an ng-repeat. Problem description could be improved ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT

I finally got it working through a directive.

**Description:** It is a timing issue. When you call the `document.querySelectorAll` inside the controller - only one image is available at that time (the one outside your ng-repeat). Then the ng-repeat runs and adds further images to the DOM - but they haven't made it through the wheelzoom call.

I have added this directive, which directly has access to the DOM element itself and calls `wheelzoom` on it.

```
app.directive('bsWheelzoom', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      wheelzoom(elem[0]);
    }
  }
})
```

The usage in the HTML is

```
<div data-ng-repeat="d in data" style="width: 300px">
      <img class="imgInsideOfAngular" ng-src="{{d.img}}" alt="{{d.title}}" width="100%" bs-wheelzoom/>
    </div>
```

#### Workin Plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjKfqKHGmCvP3LLxH0eg?p=preview

## OLD

As your `wheelzoom()` call is outside the angular world, you need to call `$scope.$apply()`.

The angular documentation states:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life-cycle of exception handling, executing watches

This fixes your issue:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img.aa'));
})
```

See this working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeqtxp65/

Comment: I think your problem was that your jsfiddle wasn't showing any image data on the ng-repeat, right? The wheelzoom itself doesn't work for me in the fiddle in general. I am currently not at my developer machine - I would like to test it locally (not on jsfiddle), but let me know if that was your actual problem and if the `$scope.$apply` fixed your issue. Hint: you are using anguar 1.0 (an older version of AngularJS - I would recommend using 1.3 or higher)

Comment: it does not work even using  $scope.$apply() and updating angular version to 1.4

Comment: I already tested it locally but it does not work work when using ng-repeat.

Comment: Have you seen my edits It should be working now with the directive.